# Do gluons mediate the interactions between different flavors of quark?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, strong-force, gluons

From some of the quite professional sources ([Basics from QCD by CERN](https://indico.cern.ch/event/555909/contributions/2265204/attachments/1324896/1988461/LHC_school_2016.pdf); [QCD from PDG](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2021/reviews/rpp2020-rev-qcd.pdf)), the QCD lagrangian is written in the form of

$$
L = \Sigma_{f} \; \bar{\psi}^{(f)} i \gamma^\mu D_\mu \psi^{(f)} + F_{a \mu \nu}F^{a \mu \nu}
$$

This lagrangian excludes the interaction between different flavors $f=1 .. 6$ of quarks mediated by the gluons.

The gluons are said to be "flavor blind", ignoring the flavor at all, which can either mean coupling only the quarks of the same flavor (as shown by this lagrangian) or coupling between different flavors in the same way.

If gluons couple only the same flavors, who is responsible for binding the different flavors? Say, in a proton? Or is this lagrangian a misleading yet very common mistake? Or is my interpretation wrong?

Note: There seem to be other sources that take care of the inter-flavor interactions. [GSI slides](http://theory.gsi.de/%7Eebratkov/LecturesWS1819/Lecture_QCD.pdf)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is very simple. For example, let's consider QED with an electron and muon field,
$$\mathcal{L} = \bar{\mu} (i \gamma^\mu D_\mu - m_\mu) \mu + \bar{e} (i\gamma^\mu D_\mu - m_e) e - \frac14 F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}.$$
There is no term in the Lagrangian that directly couples a muon field and an electron field. So does this mean muons and electrons don't interact with each other electromagnetically? Of course not. A muon can emit a photon, which is then absorbed by an electron. The *act* of emitting a photon can't change a muon into an electron, but that doesn't mean they don't interact.

The answer to your question is exactly the same. Quarks can emit gluons, though this process does not change their flavor. Those gluons can then interact with quarks of *different* flavors, i.e. they mediate an interaction between different quark flavors.

Comment: That is a great answer. Few more questions, what prohibits the cross-flavor coupling terms in the Lagrangian? Can I write down a Lagrangian that explicitly contains the couplings? Or how can I see that it is flavor-blind? Is the Lagrangian shown here with the quark fields written in direct product containing the couplings? http://theory.gsi.de/~ebratkov/LecturesWS1819/Lecture_QCD.pdf

Comment: @王凯越KaiyueWang There is absolutely nothing that prohibits cross-flavor coupling terms. However, whenever such terms exist, you can always define new fields in terms of the old ones, so that the new fields not have any cross-flavor couplings. We always do this, because it makes the calculations simpler.

Comment: @王凯越KaiyueWang In more complicated cases, such as in the full Standard Model, it is not possible to redefine the fields to get rid of all cross-flavor couplings. By convention, we define the quark fields so that cross-flavor couplings vanish for all interactions except for those with $W$ bosons. You could choose a different convention, but it would be confusing.